# Angular Transition not working using directive and queries

Tags: angular, transition

I have been trying to add transitions into my Angular application, but have not been successful. I am guessing this has to do with supplying my transition directive with the correct information or my negligence of updating routeLinkActive through the rest of my app (however, I am not sure if this is even relevant). The code is simple enough, so where did I go wrong?

My infrastructure is incredibly modest right now, so I hope you find it easy to sort through :).

I am using Angular CLI 13.1.1

**BrowserAnimationsModule** is added to *app.module.txt*

*app.component.html*

```
<body>
    <app-nav-menu></app-nav-menu>
    <div [@routeAnimations] = "getOutlet(o)">
        <router-outlet #o = "outlet"></router-outlet>
    </div>
</body>
```

*app.component.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { fade } from './route-animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  animations: [fade]
})
export class AppComponent {

  //Keep for extensibility
  getOutlet(outlet: RouterOutlet) {
    return outlet;
  }

}
```

*route-animations.ts*

```
import { trigger, transition, style, query, group, animate} from '@angular/animations';

export const fade =
  trigger('routeAnimations', [
    transition('* <=> *', [
      query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'fixed', width: '100%' }), { optional: true }),
      query(':enter', [style({ opacity: 0 })], { optional: true }),
      group([
        query(':leave', [animate('0.3s ease-out', style({ opacity: 0 }))], { optional: true }),
        query(':enter', [style({ opacity: 0 }),animate('0.3s ease-out', style({ opacity: 1 })),], { optional: true }),
      ]),
  ]),
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer! The directive in *app.component.html* needs to react to the changing in routes, so in *app.component.ts* `getOutlet(outlet)` look like the following:

```js
getOutlet(outlet: RouterOutlet) {
    return outlet?.activatedRouteData?;
}
```